# yii2 image not saved in database and can't move to folder

Tags: php, yii2

I want to upload the image and i want to save the image name in database and move the image to the folder..

But now i can't save any thing.

After uploading the file and submit the form the following error will be displayed

```
Error (#2)
An internal server error occurred.
```

My codes are below

In Views:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' =>   'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
        <?php echo  $form->field($model, 'varImage')->fileInput() ?>
        <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo Html::submitButton('Add', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary',  'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

In Models:

```
class Usertype extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['varImage'], 'safe'],
            [['varImage'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'varImage' => 'Image',
        ];
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
$model = new Usertype();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) 
{   
    $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'varImage');
    $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->varImage;
    if($model->save())
    {
        $image->saveAs($path);
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'User type inserted successfully');
        return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('/yii2/site/usertype');
    }
}
```

I can't know what error in this code

Kindly help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in your logs (or activated them if they aren't active yet?). An internal server error can literally be caused by 1000 different things, perhaps not even related to the code you posted here. 
If you add `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);` to your index.php it should normally start dumping stack traces on the screen as well.

Comment: After i choose the image and submit the form and i print the model.The model is empty.So the image is not get how to get the image in post

Comment: We need the **actual error information**. An internal server error just says "something went wrong".

Comment: How to display the actual Error in yyi

Comment: Why do I even bother replying if you don't read anything.

Comment: 1st, `Yii::$app->params['uploadPath']` - is actual param? 2nd - check $path exists, 3rd - check rights to this $path

Comment: i can't get the image in post

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
$fileupload = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

if(!empty($fileupload)){
        $fileupload->saveAs('uploads/' . $fileupload->baseName . '.' . $fileupload->extension);
        $model->image = $fileupload->baseName . '.' . $fileupload->extension;
        $model->save();
}
```

In views:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput()->label('Upload Photo') ?>
```

In models:

```
['image','safe']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your view and model code is OK.
Try this. This is your controller code. It has worked for me.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

              $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'varImage');
              if(!empty($image)){
                  $image->saveAs('uploads/' . $image->baseName . '.' . $image->extension);
                  $model->your_database_field_name = $image->baseName . '.' . $image->extension;
                  $model->save();
              }

              return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
          }
```

Comment: Image not move to folder save only in database

Comment: $image->saveAs('uploads/' . $image->baseName . '.' . $image->extension); 
This code is responsible for saving the image in folder. There can only be 2 reason either the path is wrong or the permissions are not given to the folder.

Apart from these i can't think anything else right now.